# Android Studio Error: Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android-studio

i cant fix this error

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.8/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx256ml

Answer (score 1):

Open **gradle.properties** in root of android project and check what all lines are commented out. I think, this problem occurs when you don't have enough RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your vmoptions file is somehow corrupted.

If you can start Studio, then you can edit these settings from the Android Studio menu. Open *Help->Edit Custom VM Options*. Check to make sure the `-Xmx` line has something like `-Xmx256m`.  The error line you posted above seems to indicate that there is somehow an extra `l` at the end of the line. If there is, remove just the `l`, save and restart.

If you can't start Studio, then you need to manually edit `studio.vmoptions` or `studio64.vmoptions`, depending on your installation.  These files are located a local preferences directory with a name dependent on the version you are running. See [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration) for the different possibilities. For me (64-bit Ubuntu 16.04, Studio 2.1), `studio64.vmoptions` is located in `~/.AndroidStudio2.1`. Do not edit the `vmoptions` file in the installation directory (unless of course this is where the problem was introduced).